# not inserting data into tables with form trigger failure

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I put a code on key next item which work partly I don't know why please help me if anyone knows about this using form 10g with oracle database 11g code is this

```
IF
     :BUNDLE_NUM = :USER_ID
        THEN INSERT INTO 
         PROD_CUT_ISSU_DTL
         (TRANS_ID,TRNAS_DET_ID,ORDER_NUM,ARTICLE_ID,QTY,PROD_OPEN_ID,OPER_CODE)
         VALUES
         (:PAY_IN_OUT.ISS_T_ID, :PAY_IN_OUT.ISS_TRNAS_DET_ID, A,
         B, :PROD_STCH_PROD_EMP_DET.ISS_TOT, 1 , :PROD_STCH_PROD_EMP_DET.OPER_CODE);
         
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;     
        GO_ITEM('PAY_IN_OUT.USER_ID');
        CLEAR_FORM(NO_VALIDATE);
END IF;
```

works fine when doing separate separate portion like if I run only this code it will work

```
IF
     :BUNDLE_NUM = :USER_ID
        THEN INSERT INTO 
         PROD_CUT_ISSU_DTL
         (TRANS_ID,TRNAS_DET_ID,ORDER_NUM,ARTICLE_ID,QTY,PROD_OPEN_ID,OPER_CODE)
         VALUES
         (:PAY_IN_OUT.ISS_T_ID, :PAY_IN_OUT.ISS_TRNAS_DET_ID, A,
         B, :PROD_STCH_PROD_EMP_DET.ISS_TOT, 1 , :PROD_STCH_PROD_EMP_DET.OPER_CODE);
END IF;
```

Or just run this code its working

```
IF
     :BUNDLE_NUM = :USER_ID
        THEN
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;     
        GO_ITEM('PAY_IN_OUT.USER_ID');
        CLEAR_FORM(NO_VALIDATE);
END IF;
```

Please if any one know where I am doing wrong please correct me Respects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
```

looks *terribly* wrong. Basically, you're doing *something* (inserting a row) and then immediately raise an error. That just won't work.

Raise an error when you want to **prevent** something to happen (e.g. in exception handling section).

I suggest you remove it.

---

Also, note that `KEY-NEXT-ITEM` won't work if someone navigates through the form using a **mouse**.

Comment: thanks I did also this but even clear_form is also making it to not insert i did already this. but in my scenario it will clear the form when user card scanned so at that point I have to clear the form and insert all other data into table which was first scanned

Comment: in scenario there are item scanned when user enter his card form have to do this code. if i have another option please guide me

Comment: After INSERT, you should COMMIT (if you want to preserve data in the table). RAISE nor CLEAR_FORM won't help at all (in storing data).